# octave: No function and no method found error

Tags: matlab, octave

I get the following error trying to solve a non linear system in Octave:

> error: @Jfun: no function and no method found
>   error: called from
>      voc at line 4 column 13

I'm using 4 scripts and I couldn't find the source of the error. The `ffun`, `jfun` and `newtonsys` files have been tested before and I am almost sure the issue is not there (I don't know if it could be an issue with the naming of variables though), but I have included them all below just in case.

**file voc.m**

```
x0=[9;8;0.5];
tol=10^-3;
nmax=1000;
[z,res,niter]=newtonsys(@Ffun,@Jfun,x0,tol,nmax)
```

**File Ffun.m**

```
q=1.602E-19;
k=1.381E-23;
Ncs=12;
Tc=329.25;
gamma=1.35;
Isc=9.14;
Rsh=94.5;
Vmp=37.8;
Imp=8.74;
function F=Ffun(x)
    F(1,1)=Isc+x(2)*[exp((q*Isc*x(3))/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-1]-(Isc*x(3))/Rsh-x(1);
    F(2,1)=x(2)*[exp(q*(Voc)/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-1]+(Voc/Rsh)-x(1);
    F(3,1)=Imp+x(2)*[exp(q*(Vmp+Imp*x(3))/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-1]+(Vmp+(Imp*x(3)))/Rsh-x(1);
endfunction
```

**File JFun.m**

```
q=1.602E-19;
k=1.381E-23;
Ncs=12;
Tc=329.25;
gamma=1.35;
Isc=9.14;
Rsh=94.5;
Vmp=37.8;
Imp=8.74;
function J=Jfun(x)
    J(1,1)=-1;
    J(1,2)=exp((q*Isc*x(3))/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-1;
    J(1,3)=x(2)*[exp((q*Isc*x(3))/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))]*(q*Isc/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-(Isc/Rsh);
    J(2,1)=-1;
    J(2,2)=exp(q*(Voc)/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-1;
    J(2,3)=0;
    J(3,1)=-1;
    J(3,2)=exp(q*(Vmp+Imp*x(3))/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))-1;
    J(3,3)=x(2)*[exp(q*(Vmp+Imp*x(3))/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))]*(q*Imp/(gamma*k*Tc*Ncs))+(Imp/Rsh);
endfunction
```

**file newtonsys.m**

```
function [x,res,niter] = newtonsys(Ffun,Jfun,x0,tol,...
                                nmax, varargin)
    niter = 0;
    err = tol + 1;
    x = x0;
    while err >= tol & niter < nmax
        J = Jfun(x,varargin{:});
        F = Ffun(x,varargin{:});
        delta = - J\F;
        x = x + delta;
        err = norm(delta);
        niter = niter + 1;
    end

    res = norm(Ffun(x,varargin{:}));
    if (niter==nmax & err> tol)
        fprintf(['Il metodo non converge nel massimo ',...
           'numero di iterazioni. L''ultima iterata\n',...
           'calcolata ha residuo relativo pari a %e\n'],F);
    else
        fprintf(['Il metodo converge in %i iterazioni',...
            ' con un residuo pari a %e\n'],niter,F);
    end

    return
```

Comment: I think this is a good example where a MINIMAL example would help. Try to remove as much cruft as possible until you face the problem with a few lines. In most cases you'll find then the problem yourself

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `JFun.m` file is NOT a function file, it is a script file which happens to define an 'on-the-spot' function `JFun` within it. If the `voc.m` script happens to call that function *before* it has been defined (i.e. before the `JFun.m` script has had a chance to be run and therefore end up defining that function in the current environment) then it will complain it's not there.

The solution in your case is to move all those variable definitions inside the function block, making it a proper 'function file', which will then be accessible from voc (as long as it's on the same directory / in the octave path).

Alternatively, if you still prefer `JFun.m` to be a script, (e.g. maybe you *do* want all those variables to end up being defined at global scope), then simply make sure you run it as a script *first*, such that it first defines the function you need; however, in that case, it is a good idea to change the name of your script to something else, so that its name doesn't conflict with the on-the-spot function defined inside it.

Have a quick look at the [respective section](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts) in the manual, and in particular [this](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Script-Files.html#Script-Files) part.

Comment: mind you, the same should have applied for Ffun; the reason you're not getting an error for that one may be that you've accidentally "run" Ffun before voc, so now it's defined.